# Outlook Tasks sync with Exchange?

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, tasks

I use a desktop PC in the office, and have been issued a laptop for telework (both Windows 7). I use Outlook 2010 in both cases to connect to the enterprise Exchange server for email, calendar, etc.

I set up a number of recurring tasks on the desktop. (Simple daily reminders for each weekday.) As I expected, those tasks also appear on the laptop. Great so far.

However, the "marked done" flag *isn't* being synchronized with the Exchange server. I haven't teleworked in a month and a bit, and when I fired up Outlook on the laptop I had to mark "complete" every recurring task since the last time I teleworked. I have a couple of tasks today that I'll mark done, and when I go to the office tomorrow those tasks in the desktop version of Outlook will be sitting there as overdue.

Why isn't the "marked done" setting synchronizing with my Exchange account? Is there a setting I need to adjust? Or is it something to do with how the tasks are set up?

Comment: Have you asked your IT department about this problem?

Comment: @Ramhound: No, because 1) asking IT for anything is generally an exercise in frustration, and 2) I wanted to make sure it wasn't something I've done wrong. It's mostly just an annoyance, but if I can't figure it out I'll go that route.

Comment: Well [this](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Sync-basics--what-you-can-and-cannot-sync-5537d587-4930-4ac2-b044-3568509b1294) mentions no such limitation on Tasks.  So I suspect this is a server and or client configuration problem.

Comment: @Ramhound: Okay, I can take it up with them. "There should be no such limitation (source); check with your IT department" is an answer. (Though not the one I was hoping for.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the tasks are caches locally instead of updating in exchange. Can you try from your laptop to go to the account settings and on the email tab choose your email account and click change, then under the server section try to untick the used cached exchange mode option and finish, then restart your outlook. This way instead of caching all the data on your laptop it will pick up everything live from the exchange.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm locked out of changing that setting.